# Python pulp adding a penalty

Tags: python, pulp, minimization

Currently I am working on a pulp lineair minimization problem. The variable `X`is equal to the sum of a list of numbers in this problem. If X positive, no penalty should be added to the objective. However, if `X` is negative, this should be added to the as penalty to the objective. This means that the `Penalty` should be equal to `-X` in that case.

For instance:

```
X = lpvariable('X'-1000,1000,cat='Integer')
Penalty =lpvariable('Penalty', 0,1000,cat='Integer') 
prob += Penalty # Objective 
prob += 10 + 11 + -2 + -4 == X
```

In this case `X=15` and `Penalty=0`

However when the sum would be

```
prob += -10+11-2-4 ==X
```

The variable`X=-5` and the penalty should be `Penalty = 5`

Could somebody help me with this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the constraint on `Penalty`. You pretty much say what this needs to be in your question.

You want to force `Penalty` to be `>=` to `-X`.

When `X` is positive this will have no effect - the lower bound on `Penalty` is already zero so adding another lower bound of `-X` where `X` is a positive number does nothing.

When `X` is negative it does just what you want:

```
from pulp import *
X = LpVariable('X',-1000,1000,cat='Integer')
Penalty =LpVariable('Penalty', 0,1000,cat='Integer')
prob = LpProblem ("MinimisePenaltye", LpMinimize)
prob += Penalty # Objective
prob += Penalty >= -X
prob += X == -15
prob.solve()

# Dislay the optimums of each var
for v in prob.variables ():
    print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Returns

```
Penalty = 15.0
X = -15.0
```